# Proper way of calculating descriptive statistics for probabilities

Tags: python, probability

I have 64 probabilities calculated for the same outcome using 64 different methods. I was wondering which is the correct way (if there is) to find, e.g. a mean and std for the above-mentioned population. If I do something like:

```
import numpy as np
probability_vector = calc_probabilites_using_64_methods(my_data)
# probability_vector.shape => (64,1)
mean_prob = np.mean(probability_vector)
std_prob = np.std(probability_vector)
```

I get the mean probability of all the methods and their std. The thing is that the mean probability is 5.3% and the standard deviation is 16% which gives a negative probability in the lower limit, i.e. mean - std. Is this a correct approach?

I want somehow to say "Here are the 64 individual probabilities using each one of the 64 methods, and here is the 'mean' probability with its confidence interval.'.

Comment: This isn't a programming question but a statistics question.

Comment: Long story short - given a set of probabilities (which in our case are just 64 random variables, they do not necessarily spread in the range [mean-std, mean+std]. It's a little bit more complex than that...

Comment: @mkrieger1 I thought that the answer might involve programming; that's the reason I post it here.

Comment: @noamgot could you please elaborate?

Comment: @laza - a simple example - consider the sample `[100,100,100,100,1]` (or if we're talking about probs, let's go with `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.01]`. A simple calculation shows that the mean is ~0.8 and the standard deviation is ~0.39. Clearly `0.01 < 0.41 = 0.8-0.39`, yet 0.01 is still in our sample. The conclusion is that there's nothing wrong with the example you gave - it is possible that `mean-std < 0`.

Comment: @noamgot Alright. What I was thinking was to approximate the distribution defined by the probabilities and use that distribution to extract appropriate statistics.

Comment: I don't believe conditions of CLT and converging to gaussian is applicable here. What you're summing up is definitely not sequence of iid rn.

Comment: What should I do then ?